# What is the cost of measurement?

Tags: entanglement, measurement

I am exploring a quantum algorithm to solve a partial derivative equation with time derivative. It performs the same entangling unitary to advance the solution by one time step.

Is it more efficient to:

- measure all the qubits at the end of every time step, which requires re-preparing the states for the next time step using measurement outcomes (version1)?
- or run the circuit for the total time steps needed and delay measurement to the end of the computation (version2)?

These are my thoughts so far:
From the one hand, I know qubits have finite coherence times. So version2 may not be good because it increases circuit depth. From the other hand, measuring all qubits destroys quantum information and entanglement. So version1 doesn't fully use quantum advantage.

I appreciate any insights into the difference between these two versions in terms of efficiency and potential quantum speedup.

Thank you in advance.